# How to create an App package for WinUI Projects?

Tags: c#, continuous-integration, package

I can create my msbuild app package for WinUI via manual app package creation method.
But, I need to create a App package through command line.

```
msbuild mysolution.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release;OutDir=D:\#Development\CI\AppPack;Platform="x86|ARM"
```

When I execute the above command in Powershell, I am facing the below Errors.

[image]

So, suggest me any solution for create an app package for WinUI through command line.

Comment: Is your directory really called `#Development`?

Comment: Hi  @JamesZ  Yes it is called #Development. Is there any problem with make directory with '#'.